# Maintaining a bunch of generic functions

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a better way to manage a bunch of generic functions? These all have a implementation that look almost the same. Changing them however is a monks job atm.

The interface that's implemented looks like this:

```
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, TResult>, T1, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, TResult>, T1, T2, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TResult> func);
 IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TResult> func);
```

Pretty but you can emagine how the implementation looks. And what if I want to change something to the signature of these methods.

Comment: Oh and there's also a list like this for Action<T1..T15>

Comment: What about generating them compile-time using a T4 template?

Comment: :) I don't think that's pretty at all

Comment: @user1477388 This is Op-art in c#

Comment: I'd like a good answer to this but I've always assummed thats just the way it is. Of course you don't have to limit yourself to `Action<T1, ..., T16>` why not create your own `Action<T1, ..., T999>`. Of course, thats only marginally less bizarre than sixteen parameters.

Comment: You know, there is a `region` thing to hide things you don't want to see.

Comment: @Jodrell I think it's because intellisense can only handle somewhere around 16 implementations without taking an age to show up :)

Comment: @Sinatr I though regions only existed to make StyleCop complain.

Comment: you almost want something like `Delegate<params Type[]>(params object[])` but its "sort-of" anti-generic.

Comment: @Jodrell they are all converted to a `Func<Func<object[], object>, object[], object>` and then to a `Func<Delegate, object[], object>` :)

Comment: This is ASCII art depicting lines of slope -1, -2 and -3.

Comment: +1 for the use of the phrase "monks job" :)

Comment: I'm having problems even imagining why you'd want to make such a gigantic collection of generics. Apply a bit of YAGNI and only use the bits you _actually_ need?

Comment: @DonalFellows You're absolutely right. I'm not going to need all of them. But how many is a reasonable? :). I jus thought I'd max out the funcs provided by the CLR.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is possible implementation of T4 template which generates your interface:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#  const int maxParametersCount = 15; #>
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public interface IInterceptable<T>
{
<# for(int parametersCount = 1; parametersCount <= maxParametersCount; parametersCount++) { 
   string parameters = String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, parametersCount).Select(i => "T" + i));         
#>    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<<#= parameters #>, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<<#= parameters #>, TResult>, <#= parameters #>, TResult> func);
<#}#>
}
```

You need only provide `maxParametersCount` value. If you will provide `15` it will generate following interface declaration:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public interface IInterceptable<T>
{
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, TResult>, T1, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, TResult>, T1, T2, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TResult> func);
    IProxy<T> AddInterceptor<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TResult>(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TResult>, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TResult> func);
}
```

Of course, you can add some namespace to generated code.

Comment: You sir are awesome, this is what I ended up making. https://gist.github.com/albertjan/9468027

Answer (score 11):

You could use T4 templates to automatically generate code with N number of types.  If you need to change slightly implementation, you simply edit your template and regenerate.  And if you previously generated for 15, and now need 30, simply change your boundary and regenerate.

The greater question here is design - it's a bit of a suspect as to why this is needed in the first place.  It may be worth to re-examine that part.

Comment: The implementation is mostly to create a nicer api. So you have intellismell when your writing the delegate. Eventually they're all passed into this function: `IProxy<T> AddInterceptor(Expression<Action<T>> functionOrProperty, Func<Func<object[], object>, object[], object> func);`

Comment: Could you expand on why this would be bad design?

Comment: @albertjan Well, maintenance pain - as you discovered - would be my primary argument against it (even with T4 use). Code readability is likely to suffer. Without knowing how it is used it's hard to be more specific, but in general terms, I suppose it is in a way similar to having a function with 15 overloads of identical arguments differing in count, rather than say instead take an array of same 15 arguments and have just one function signature.  Note, I'm not saying that there cannot be a valid case for it, just that it may call for a sanity check. It may well be best approach in your case...

Comment: Like I said all these functions are to make the api of this project easier to use and are all routed to a single function containing the logic. This is a public API so I do want to explicitly declare the options. Sanity checked :) T4 add as much code to render this code as it is to implement I don't know if I really like adding that.

Comment: @comeAndGo instead of saying it's bad design or a design issue why answer the question. Explaining how you would solve it and why this solution is a bad one.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, and you have one already. I just read through the code and I **know** that anything that cumbersome and lengthy indicates poor design, perhaps much further upstream. In the name of Einstein it is said: "When the solution is simple, God is answering".

Comment: @comeAndGo see http://github.com/Curit/DynamicProxy and see if you can create a typesafe API for adding Interceptors to the proxy without making these 15 overloades. Microsoft also makes 16 Funcs and 16 Actions and don't call everything a Delegate and let you handle the parameters blindly. I asked this question because I too wondered if this could be done differently. But apparently the Framework doesn't provide a short cut for these kinds of situations.

Comment: @albertjan -  _But apparently the Framework doesn't provide a short cut for these kinds of situations_ - I said the problem might be "much further upstream" :) I'm not a huge MS/ .NET fan... don't care for their software.

Answer (score 9):

This seems like an ideal use for T4 Templates...
If you haven't used them they allow you to write code that generates code. Anything this tedious that seems like a robot could do it - perfect application.

If you change something in the signature you simply change it in the t4 template and your .cs file will be updated automatically with the new signature.

Comment: Though it may be the solution I don't know what's worse. T4 is seriously hideous :P

Comment: @albertjan Haahaa, yeah I understand the reluctance. One thing I've found is that most T4 resources show the asp like syntax <% my completely illegible code block%> which when you are nesting complex code inside other complex code is completely terrible...  The other syntax using WriteLine, PushIndent, etc leads to some almost readable code... You are dealing with strings so it isn't gorgeous but it is much less suicide inducing to debug. It also makes it easier to control your output indentation so you don't make yourself insane if you are a stickler for formatting.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a42a8538-8d6e-491b-8097-5a8a00174d37 this helps when writing the T4 templates in VS :)